# change loop direction if condition met

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a loop that will go stepwise if ZuluLY > ZuluTY , and reverse stepwise if Zulu < ZuluTY

I keep getting the "else without if" compile error when i try this.
The loop works fine without the IF statement conditioning, but when I add the IF statement in, i get the error.

Here is a code snippet showing what I have tried

```
If ZuluLY > ZuluTY Then
For yr = LBound(Year_Arr) To UBound(Year_Arr)
ElseIf ZuluLY < ZuluTY Then
For yr = UBound(Year_Arr) To LBound(Year_Arr) Step -1
End If 
'..... code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim vStart, vEnd, vStep

If ZuluLY > ZuluTY Then
    vStart = LBound(Year_Arr)
    vEnd = UBound(Year_Arr)
    vStep = 1
else
    vStart = UBound(Year_Arr)
    vEnd = LBound(Year_Arr)
    vStep = -1
end if


For yr = vStart To vEnd Step vStep
```

Comment: Ah ha! I didn't think of assigning it to a variable. Thank you so much, Tim!